# R changing variable value of one factor level to represent value mean of factor levels by day

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
> df
            Time_Start            Time_End Cut Plot Inlet_NH4N Outlet_NH4N Pump_reading Anemometer_reading
1  2016-05-05 11:19:00 2016-05-06 09:30:00   1    1  0.2336795  0.30786350      79846.9            6296343
2  2016-05-05 11:25:00 2016-05-06 09:35:00   1    3  1.0905045  0.50816024      78776.5             333116
3  2016-05-05 11:33:00 2016-05-06 09:39:00   1    6  1.3538576  0.34866469      79585.1            8970447
4  2016-05-05 11:37:00 2016-05-06 09:51:00   1    7  0.6862018  0.34124629      80043.1            8436546
5  2016-05-05 11:43:00 2016-05-06 09:43:00   1    9  0.2633531  0.73813056      79227.7            9007387
6  2016-05-05 11:48:00 2016-05-06 09:47:00   1   12  0.5934718  1.10905045      79121.5            8070785
7  2016-05-06 09:33:00 2013-05-07 10:13:00   1    1  0.5213904  2.46791444      88800.2            7807792
8  2016-05-06 09:38:00 2013-05-07 10:23:00   1    3  0.1684492  0.22905526      89123.0              14127
9  2016-05-06 09:42:00 2013-05-07 10:28:00   1    6  0.4393939  0.09001782      89157.6            9844162
10 2016-05-06 09:53:00 2013-05-07 10:34:00   1    7  0.1470588  1.03832442      88852.6            9143733
11 2016-05-06 09:45:00 2013-05-07 10:40:00   1    9  0.1114082  0.32531194      89635.6           10122720
12 2016-05-06 09:50:00 2013-05-07 10:43:00   1   12  0.6853832  2.51426025      89582.6            8924198
```

Here is the `str`:

```
> str(df)

'data.frame':   12 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Time_Start        : POSIXct, format: "2016-05-05 11:19:00" "2016-05-05 11:25:00" "2016-05-05 11:33:00" ...
 $ Time_End          : POSIXct, format: "2016-05-06 09:30:00" "2016-05-06 09:35:00" "2016-05-06 09:39:00" ...
 $ Cut               : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Plot              : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","3","6","7",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ Inlet_NH4N        : num  0.234 1.091 1.354 0.686 0.263 ...
 $ Outlet_NH4N       : num  0.308 0.508 0.349 0.341 0.738 ...
 $ Pump_reading      : num  79847 78777 79585 80043 79228 ...
 $ Anemometer_reading: int  6296343 333116 8970447 8436546 9007387 8070785 7807792 14127 9844162 9143733 ...
```

This is a small segment of a larger dataset.
I have a problem with these data in that the `Anemometer_reading` for `plot "3"` is always much lower than for the other plots. This is due to a mechanical problem. I want to remove this artifact and think that the best way to do this is to take an average of the `Anemometer_reading` for all the plots outwith `plot "3"`. I want to calculate this average on a daily basis.

I can calculate the daily `Anemometer_reading` average, excluding `plot "3"` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
> df_avg <- df %>% filter(Plot != "3") %>% group_by(as.Date(Time_End)) %>% summarise(Anemometer_mean = mean(Anemometer_reading))
> df_avg
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]


  as.Date(Time_End) Anemometer_mean
             <date>           <dbl>
1        2013-05-07         9168521
2        2016-05-06         8156302
```

I'm not sure how to go about using the resulting dataframe to replace the `Anemometer_reading` values from `plot "3"`.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?
Thanks

Comment: What you propose is (after implicitly setting these values to missing) something called "mean imputation". Depending on what you want to do with the result, this can introduce serious bias. I suggest you do some research first regarding imputation methods.

Comment: @Roland thanks will look into mean imputation

Comment: Look into the [Amelia 2 software](http://gking.harvard.edu/amelia) (package Amelia) for better imputation methods. It can deal nicely with time series data. But if all measurements from plot 3 are missing, you can't really impute and should probably discard the replicate.

Comment: Yes, discarding would be one option but will look into other imputation methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow @roland's comment. However, if you care about how you would use `dplyr` to do what you asked:

```
result <- df %>% group_by(as.Date(Time_End)) %>% 
                 mutate(Anemometer_mean = mean(Anemometer_reading[Plot != "3"])) %>% 
                 mutate(Anemometer_reading = replace(Anemometer_reading, Plot == "3", first(Anemometer_mean))) %>%
                 ungroup() %>% select(-`as.Date(Time_End)`, -Anemometer_mean)
print(result)
## A tibble: 12 x 8
##            Time_Start            Time_End   Cut  Plot Inlet_NH4N Outlet_NH4N Pump_reading Anemometer_reading
##                <fctr>              <fctr> <int> <int>      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>              <dbl>
##1  2016-05-05 11:19:00 2016-05-06 09:30:00     1     1  0.2336795  0.30786350      79846.9            6296343
##2  2016-05-05 11:25:00 2016-05-06 09:35:00     1     3  1.0905045  0.50816024      78776.5            8156302
##3  2016-05-05 11:33:00 2016-05-06 09:39:00     1     6  1.3538576  0.34866469      79585.1            8970447
##4  2016-05-05 11:37:00 2016-05-06 09:51:00     1     7  0.6862018  0.34124629      80043.1            8436546
##5  2016-05-05 11:43:00 2016-05-06 09:43:00     1     9  0.2633531  0.73813056      79227.7            9007387
##6  2016-05-05 11:48:00 2016-05-06 09:47:00     1    12  0.5934718  1.10905045      79121.5            8070785
##7  2016-05-06 09:33:00 2013-05-07 10:13:00     1     1  0.5213904  2.46791444      88800.2            7807792
##8  2016-05-06 09:38:00 2013-05-07 10:23:00     1     3  0.1684492  0.22905526      89123.0            9168521
##9  2016-05-06 09:42:00 2013-05-07 10:28:00     1     6  0.4393939  0.09001782      89157.6            9844162
##10 2016-05-06 09:53:00 2013-05-07 10:34:00     1     7  0.1470588  1.03832442      88852.6            9143733
##11 2016-05-06 09:45:00 2013-05-07 10:40:00     1     9  0.1114082  0.32531194      89635.6           10122720
##12 2016-05-06 09:50:00 2013-05-07 10:43:00     1    12  0.6853832  2.51426025      89582.6            8924198
```

Instead of `filter` and `summarise`, `mutate` to create a new column `Anemometer_mean` that computes the mean with all rows for `Plot!=3`. Then replace the `Anemometer_read` for those rows `Plot==3` with this mean.

In fact, you can do all this with just one `mutate`:

```
result <- df %>% group_by(as.Date(Time_End)) %>% 
                 mutate(Anemometer_reading = replace(Anemometer_reading, Plot == "3", mean(Anemometer_reading[Plot != "3"]))) %>%
                 ungroup() %>% select(-`as.Date(Time_End)`)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great, that works well. Nice to know about the `replace()' agument